# Local Storage not saving

Tags: html, local-storage

I have a form and I am trying to save the fields to local storage but the alert comes up as null And the local storage isn't saving

```
 <form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored form-control" value="" />
 <button onclick="store()" type="button" id="myButton" class="btn />
 </form>


function store(){
 var inputName= document.getElementById("name");
 window.localStorage.setItem("name", inputName.value);
 alert(name);
 }
```

Comment: couple possibilities: 1. you're alerting `name` and haven't defined that var (unless it's somewhere else). 2. is the form submit event and post method happening before the click of a submit button and disrupting your expected results? 3. is there any other relevant code that you haven't posted?

Comment: No its just this code

Comment: thank you, i add ed the following code, var name = window.localStorage.getItem('name');

Comment: If you want to alert stored value you need a function for that `getItem`, it doesn't store a variable by that name like u are trying to access. And probably you need to prevent a form from submitting.

Comment: and now it works, add it as an answer and i will click.

Comment: I just wanted to check the value was being stored

Comment: are there any errors in your console? also you did miss an ending quote at the end of `class="btn`. possible issue there

Comment: this works: https://codepen.io/scrimothy/pen/VgbyGJ
the only thing I did was close your class attribute quote, alerted the correct thing, and added text to your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call **window.localStorage.getItem("name")** to get the name from local storage in alert. Also your button tag is not closed properly. I have just formatted your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Local Storage Demo</title>
    <script>
        function store(){
            var inputName= document.getElementById("name");
            window.localStorage.setItem("name", inputName.value);
            alert(window.localStorage.getItem("name"));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <button onclick="store()" type="button" id="myButton">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```